# Get a unix timestamp in a specific timezone

Tags: php, timezone, unix-timestamp

I'm currently trying to get the timestamp of the `date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");` as unix timestamp, but it always results in a UTC unix timestamp.

```php
// Current time: "2016-04-28 20:37:20"

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// -> "2016-04-28 20:37:20"

echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
// -> 1461868642 which is Thu, 28 Apr 2016 18:37:22 GMT
// i need here 1461875840 which is the current time.
```

Comment: A timestamp, by definition, is in UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a different timestamp than the one you expect, because you're not specifying a timezone. You can get the results you're after with the following change to your code:

```
echo strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . " GMT");
```

Answer (score 1):

[By definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

> Unix time (also known as POSIX time or Epoch time) is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970.

And from the `strtotime` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC).